# How do I query complex data and return the data in the correct objects in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm just starting out with ZF2 and I've run into a stumbling block and I cant find any useful advice on the internet.

Setting up retrieval of data from a single table and injecting it directly into a specific model is easy, for example, pulling data from a single row from 'school' table and injecting to a 'school' model.

However, I have some slightly more complex data and can't figure out how to return the data in the form of the correct model. For example, pulling multiple addresses from a school address table with a join on the school table.

I've got the following method in my AddressTable object...

```
public function fetchAllSchoolAddresses($school_id)
{   
    $stmt = $this->adapter->createStatement();
    $stmt->prepare("CALL get_school_addresses(3)");
    $stmt->getResource()->bindParam(3, $school_id, \PDO::PARAM_INT, 3);
    $resultSet = $stmt->execute();

    $addresses = new \ArrayObject();

    if(!empty($resultSet)){
        foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
            $addresses->append($result);
        }
    }

    return $addresses;
}
```

This quite nicely returns an array of addresses data but I want these results to be returned as Address objects. I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Sound like: SELECT * FROM school LEFT JOIN address USING(school_id). If not please explain a bit more about your problem

Comment: Ok, sorry, perhaps the question is badly worded. I've got the query (SELECT a.*
 FROM school_address sa
 LEFT JOIN address a ON sa.address_id = a.id
 WHERE sa.school_id = school_id;). I just need to know how execute it in ZF2 and return the data in the correct objects.

Comment: DI doesn't really have anything to do with database access. What you are looking for might be a useful data model pattern. Code is good. Show us what you've tried. This question currently feels a little too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF2 comes with some standard Hydrators, which you can extend / modify if you wish.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html

You could create a Hydrator for your School Object, and a Hydrator for your Address object.
The hydrators will build the object for you given the array data from the database for example

For example, you would Hydrate your School Object, and then find all addresses (like above) and use another hydrator to hydrate those. You would then add those to the School object to get your object graph as needed

```
$school->addAddress($address); // etc
```

Have a look here to see an example of using Hydrators and Hydrating ResultSets:

http://blog.evan.pro/zf2-tablegateway-hydration
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

for exampple you could do something like this:

```
// How ever you want to get your database result do it here..
// this is where you get all addresses for your School
$stmt = $driver->createStatement($sql);
$stmt->prepare($parameters);
$result = $stmt->execute();

$resultSet = new HydratingResultSet(new ReflectionHydrator, new SchoolAddress);
$resultSet->initialize($result);
foreach ($resultSet as $address) {
    $school->addAddress($address);
    echo $address->getCity() . ' ' . $user->getPostcode() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You would have a resultset (collection) of Addresses to add to your School. 
That's code is just a very rough example hacked from the code in the docs to give an idea of what you do

Comment: Thanks Andrew! So, inside the foreach would I have to instantiate a new hydrator to create and hydrate a new Address per result?

Comment: There's no need for that if you use a Hydrating result set, it will create a new object for each row the database returns, they can then be added to the school object :)

Comment: see here on how to use the HydratingResultSet with a Hydrator to get back a collection of proper objects: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew this has worked perfectly, exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if(!empty($resultSet)){
    foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
        $address = new Address();
        $address->exchangeArray($result);
        $addresses->append($address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes that works. Seems a bit hacky though. Don't hydrators use the exchangeArray method anyway? Is this better or worse than using a hydrator?

Comment: A hydrator CAN use exchangeArray but it doesn't have to there's different strategies you can use. Look at ClassMethods Hydrator etc